# Android web server that can stream real time audio from local mic

Tags: android, webserver, live-streaming

I want to write a web server on Android phone. When other phone users look at the server's web page in browsers, the web page can play real time audio recorded from the server's microphone. Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!